# Question about contraction with metric tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus

I just starting to study GR and I could not prove the following: if I have to tensors $T_{\mu\nu}$ and $Q_{\mu\nu}$ such that $T_{\mu\nu}=Q_{\mu\nu}$, why can I multiply both sides of the equation by $g^{\mu\nu}$, i.e., why is valid $g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\mu\nu}$? Why some authors call it "tracing the equation with $g^{\mu\nu}$"?

Comment: Repeated indices are summed over.  What is your problem with the formalism specifically?

Comment: If $x=5$, why is it valid that I can do $2x = 10$?

Comment: If I multiply both sides of $T_{\mu\nu}=Q_{\mu\nu}$ by a scalar, than it is ok! But I cant see why I can multiply by $g^{\mu\nu}$ since there is sum implicit!

Comment: Write the sum out in components (don't need all 4 dimensions, just try two).  It should become obvious then.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$ is just another way of writing
$$
  \sum_{\mu,\nu = 0}^3 g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}
$$
Now, if we know that $T_{\mu\nu} = Q_{\mu\nu}$ for *every* $\mu,\nu = 0,\dots 3$, then we can simply substitute $Q_{\mu\nu}$ in for $T_{\mu\nu}$ in the sum.  In other words
$$
  \sum_{\mu,\nu = 0}^3 g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} = \sum_{\mu,\nu = 0}^3 g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\mu\nu}
$$
but the sum on the right can be written using the summation convention as $g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\mu\nu}$.  So, putting this all together, we have shown that
$$
  g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\nu}Q_{\mu\nu}
$$
Authors call it "tracing" because they are making an analogy with taking the trace of a matrix.  Note, in particular, that if $g^{\mu\nu} = \delta^{\mu\nu}$ then we would have
$$
  g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} = \delta^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\mu} = \sum_{\mu=0}^3T_{\mu\mu} =\mathrm{tr}(T) 
$$
where $T$ is the matrix with components $T_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Hello, it should be $T_{\mu\mu}$ in the last equation after summing over $\nu$ with the delta function.

Comment: @robert sure thang brotha.